# Nesting event triggers in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

*I'm a newbie at jQuery, so I'm having a hard time phrasing my question.*

How do I go about triggering an event while already in another event?

**My situation:** I'm making a social-icon-menu in the footer of a website. When I hover over the div container I want all the icons to go from grey to white. When I hover over a single icon, I want that icon to go from white to yellow.

I can make each event happen on their own, but not together.

```
//event on the div container id=social
$("#social").mouseover(function(){
  $(".socicon").css("color", "white");
  }).mouseleave(function(){
  $(".socicon").css("color", "grey");
});

//event on the p class=socicon
$(".socicon").mouseover(function(){
  $(this).css("color", "yellow");
  }).mouseleave(function(){
  $(this).css("color", "white");
});
```

How would I make these work together? And why are they not working together now?

Thanks!

Comment: `.socicon` is a child of `#social`? -> [`event.stopPropagation()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

Comment: Hi shawnparrotte, would you mind supplying your html? It would make it easier to answer your question accurately.

Comment: You can also achieve this effect by just using css property `hover`. On outer div hover set its color white, and when hover on the icon, set the icon color to yellow. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Ahover

Comment: Andreas, yes .socicon is a child of #social. I'll take a look at what you mentioned.

Sagar, I wanted to add some extra effects on after I got the main functionality working, so that's why I went with jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can (and should) be done strictly with CSS:

```css
.social-icon-menu {
  background: #CCC;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.social-icon-menu ul { list-style-type: none; padding: 0px; }
.social-icon-menu li { display: inline-block; margin: 10px; }
.social-icon-menu a { color: gray; }
.social-icon-menu:hover a { color: white; }
.social-icon-menu:hover a:hover { color: yellow; }
```

```html
<footer>
    <nav class="social-icon-menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</footer>
```

...but, if you want to know why your jQuery-based solution isn't working, it seems to be because of how the styles are overriding each other. To avoid overriding the same styles, apply one color option to a parent element and use `color: inherit` as the default. See snippet:

```js
//event on the div container id=social
$('#social').mouseover(function(){
    $('#social').css('color', 'white');
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $('#social').css('color', '');
});

//event on the p class=socicon
$('.socicon').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).css('color', 'yellow');
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).css('color', 'inherit');
});
```

```css
.social-icon-menu { background: #CCC; width: 500px; margin: 0px auto; text-align: center; color: gray }
.social-icon-menu ul { list-style-type: none; padding: 0px; }
.social-icon-menu li { display: inline-block; margin: 10px; }
.social-icon-menu a { color: inherit; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<footer>
    <nav class="social-icon-menu">
        <ul id="social">
            <li><a href="#" class="socicon">link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="socicon">link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="socicon">link 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="socicon">link 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</footer>
```

Comment: That was it. Thank you. Gotta spend some more time with inherit then huh?

Comment: Inheriting color like this usually happens automatically in default styling of other tags, so it's not very often that you'll need it. But, in the case of anchor tags, there are default color styles already applied that need to be overridden.